# sentiment analysis for arabic language

Tags: java, nlp, sentiment-analysis, rapidminer

I'm looking for analysing sentiment in arabic language , to do that I collect some status from facebook and I classify them into positive and negative , I'm using RapidMiner software so I do the tokenization and stemmig and stop words remove , now I want that my corpus consider the emoticons " :( and :) " as a positive and begative sentiment , how to add that to my corpus.

[image]

this the model that I used , what operator I have to incorporate in order to deal with smileys as positive and negative sentiment

Comment: Providing the relevant code that you're working with would help get you useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Tokenization will typically remove punctuation.  Are you implementing your own tokenizer to avoid this?  Perhaps a custom [TokenMarker](http://rapid-i.com/api/rapidminer-5.1/com/rapidminer/gui/tools/syntax/TokenMarker.html)?

Comment: how to create my own tokenizer ?? I used the tokenizer operator with the non letters parameter